# .yaml file not running in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, yaml

I am trying to find an extension that will run my pubspec.yaml file in vscode for my flutter app but am not having much success. Currently getting the following error when I try to run the file:

`Code language not supported or defined. Source: Code Runner (Extension)`

Comment: yaml is a datastore, you can't run it

Comment: Thank you @rioV8 ! Must have been obvious for you. Saved me quite some time! I appreciate it!